# symfony2: How to add an "active" html class if the current route matches in twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have this block and I want to include it in some pages

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs padding-18">
    <li class="active">
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show') }}">Profile</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_edit') }}">Edit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="{{ path('friends') }}">Friends</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The first tag **< li >** has class named **"active"** , how can I applicate this class dynamically for the second or third tag **< li >** when I change the page ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare the current route against the link's one and add the active class if it matches.

Use the **[ternary operator](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators)** for a nice short syntax:

```
<li{{ (app.request.attributes.get('_route') == 'fos_user_profile_show') ? ' class="active"' }}>
```

Comment: mine doesn't render the empty `class=""` if the route doesn't match. less html output => faster pageload ;)